# When getting records via the @wire function will it only grab records the User has access to?

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

If the sales AM bob is using a LWC that has an @wire that returns a *list* of accounts to be displayed will it get all the accounts or only the ones bob has access to?

I need to know because i'm creating a component and cant simply pass the userId and check to see if they're the owner.

It's the account object and i need to grab the accounts in which they can create new opportunities for. Would i have to also query the UserRecordAccess object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @wire method simply returns whatever the Apex gets. It's the *Apex* you need to secure. Make sure you're using `with sharing` or `inherited sharing`, and `UserRecordAccess`. Make sure you follow the security best practices, and you'll be fine.